# Can not delete Application after registration with azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[Registered application with Azure Active Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GezNI.png)

The button Delete is Disabled. Does anyone have any idea why i cannot delete the Application?

Comment: I do not think this issue is related to provisioning. i had other application which i created which was successfully deleted. The ones that i have been able to delete were all Web app / API types and the ones which am not able to delete are native type. I am not sure if this has any relation, just thought it  might be helpful.

Comment: @Ryu Yes, you are right. It is not related to provisioning, your app is a native app, you could not delete it directly. I add it to my answer. Hope it will help more people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot delete your application because it is set to "multi-tenant"; native clients have this property set by default.

To be able to delete the application, open the manifest editor and change:

`availableToOtherTenants=false`

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Indeed, this solved the issue. Native application had the availableToOtherTenants = true by default. Thank you Shawn.

Comment: Bang on...I am also able to delete. Thanks